# Getting patent object property values with automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have 3 class that are getting data from entity framework:

```
public class State{ 
   .......
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public IList<City> Cities{get;set;}
}

public class City{ 
     .......
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public State State{get; set;}
}

public class Empleoyee{ 
   ......
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public City City{get; set;}
}
```

I am creating a Employee summry view like this:

```
Employees
-------------------
CityStateName  CityName  Name
```

Summary class is like this:

```
public class EmpleoyeeSummaryView{ 
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public string CityName{get; set;}
   public string CityStateName{get; set;} ?????
}
```

I mapped `Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmpleoyeeSummaryView>` and `CityStateName` coming `empty/null`

```
Employees
-------------------
CityStateName  CityName  Name
               City1     Emp1
               City2     Emp2
               City1     Emp3
```

Comment: How are they mapped?

Comment: Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmpleoyeeSummaryView>

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the CityStateName is a custom property for which you have to define the translation behavior):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmpleoyeeSummaryView>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CityStateName,
               opts => opts.MapFrom(
                   src => string.Format("{0} {1}",
                       src.State.Name,
                       src.Name)));
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: In what context are you calling this translation?